# How to send message from website to android application?

Tags: android, firebase, web

I know how to create website and android applications (little more than basics).

---

I want to create a website from where user write its email or id which he already set it in android app when he send the message from website it will be received on android application(also mine) where that email or id is already set.

---

Is there any tutorial on how to do this?
To be more specific I just want to communicate from website to some specific android application(mine) by using its id.
Just refer me to tutorials where I can learn this.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial-android/

Comment: from google all i found is fcm to do this.is there any other way to perfom this function?

Comment: you could develope an own solution, but you have to request your server permanently to check if there is new data, it's not possible to initiate a connection from a server to your phone... 
fcm will be the best choice

Comment: Since asking for such recommendations is off-topic on Stack Overflow I voted to close your question. That said, I wrote this blog post a while ago for sending between Android devices. The same approach could be used for sending from a web site to an Android device: http://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Answer (score 0):

One way to communicate is via notifications(though not a standard way). For example, see [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

Comment: do you know some good tutorial on how to create fcm server i followed some on youtube they are not working?

Comment: and is there any other way to perform this function?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of app linking. You can add extras to the intent you fire from the website, which you can get when the app is opened.

Tutorial:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html